# Jquery submit form only if div contains "someText"

Tags: jquery, submit

```
<div id="field"><div class="field-item ">someText</div></div><br>

<form action="submit.php">
<input type="text" >
<button id="somediv" class="button button4" >CHECK URL</button>
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(event){


if ($('#field > div.field-item:contains("someText")').length > 0) {
    $("#somediv").removeClass("button button4");
    $("#somediv").addClass("button button2");
     $("#somediv").text("DOWNLOAD");
     setTimeout(() => {
             $("#somediv").removeClass("button button3");
              $("#somediv").addClass("button button4");
             $("#somediv").text("CHECK URL");
             location.reload();
        }, 8000);


}
else{
    $("#somediv").removeClass("button button4");
    $("#somediv").addClass("button button3");

     $("#somediv").text("THIS IS NOT VALID! ");
setTimeout(() => {
             $("#somediv").removeClass("button button3");
              $("#somediv").addClass("button button4");
             $("#somediv").text("CHECK URL");
             location.reload();
        }, 1000);




}
  });
});
</script>
```

Now , i want to submit my form when button is pressed only if item.contains "SomeText" , and prevent from submiting if div is different from that text...
I tried with to call function onsubmtit but in my case from is submitting without condition...

Answer (score 0):

To make this work first hook to the `submit` event of the `form` element, not the `click` of the `button`. Then in the `else` logic call `preventDefault()` on the event to stop the form submission.

Also note that you can cache the `#somediv` selector, and also DRY up the `setTimeout()` call. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $div = $('#somediv');

  $("form").on('submit', function(e) {
    var timeoutDelay;
    if ($('#field > div.field-item:contains("someText")').length > 0) {
      $div.removeClass("button button4").addClass("button button2").text("DOWNLOAD");
      timeoutDelay = 8000;
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();

      $div.removeClass("button button4").addClass("button button3").text("THIS IS NOT VALID");
      timeoutDelay = 1000;
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      $div.removeClass("button button3").addClass("button button4").text("CHECK URL");
      location.reload();
    }, timeoutDelay);
  });
});
```

There's a couple of things to note. Firstly this is a *very* unreliable method of validation. I would strongly suggest reconsidering how you enable the for submission.

Secondly if the validation passes the form will be submitted immediately, so your 8 second delay on the timeout and the `location.reload()` is entirely redundant.